# How to create a dictionary from one list, making the first item mapped to the second, the third mapped to the fouth, and so on

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings and integers:

```
students = ['Janet', 21, 'Bill', 19, 'Amanda', 22, 'Mike', 25, 'Susan', 24, 'Jen', 29, 'Sara', 30, 'Maria', 18, 'Kathy', 20, 'Andrew', 27]
```

I need to make a dictionary called peoples, that takes each name and maps it to their age, which is the integer after it. I thought I would have to iterate over the list, but I've had no luck. Here is what I have so far:

```
students = ['Janet', 21, 'Bill', 19, 'Amanda', 22, 'Mike', 25, 'Susan', 24, 'Jen', 29, 'Sara', 30, 'Maria', 18, 'Kathy', 20, 'Andrew', 27]
people = {}
for i in students:
    if type(i) is int == False:
        #here I would take i and make it a key in the dictionary, then map the following integer to its value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
students = ['Janet', 21, 'Bill', 19, 'Amanda', 22, 'Mike', 25, 'Susan', 24, 'Jen', 29, 'Sara', 30, 'Maria', 18, 'Kathy', 20, 'Andrew', 27]

print(dict(zip(students[::2], students[1::2])))
```

Prints:

```
{'Janet': 21, 'Bill': 19, 'Amanda': 22, 'Mike': 25, 'Susan': 24, 'Jen': 29, 'Sara': 30, 'Maria': 18, 'Kathy': 20, 'Andrew': 27}
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 20 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {}
for i in range(len(students)//2):
   dict[student[i]] = dict[student[i+1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
dict([x for x in zip(*[iter(students)]*2)])
```